# PHP Websocket on LAMP Ubuntu

Tags: php, apache, websocket, mod-proxy, ratchet

So I have been searching on this for quite some time now and tried a lot of things but just couldn't figure out how to make it work. I created a PHP WebSocket server (ratchet) on my local machine using XAMPP and an angular (v5) frontend, worked without any issues.

Then I tried to deploy both on a DigitalOcean instance where a LAMP stack is running because the app is more than just the WebSocket chat and the rest (a RESTful API) is working fine, but when the JavaScript tries to connect to the WS I get

```
 WebSocket connection to 'ws://<ip-address>:8888/chat' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

So what I did do was to enable the apache2 mods `proxy` and `proxy_wstunnel` and created an entry for a vhost

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html_backend/web

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory "/var/www/html_backend/web">
            AllowOverride All
            Allow from All
    </Directory>

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass "/chat/" "ws://localhost:8888/"
    # also tried 0.0.0.0 and 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

The PHP server socket is started like this

```
public function actionStart() {
    $app = new App('localhost', 8888, '0.0.0.0');
    $app->route('/chat', new Chat());
    $app->run();
}
```

And in JS I try connecting to this

```
this._socket = new WebSocket('ws://<ip-address>:8888/chat');
```

I also tried it on port 8080 where it should be proxied from, but then it returned a 404 error.

On port 80 I have my frontend and on port 8080 my backend, which is working so far. I can start the WebSocket on port 8888 which did not give me any errors I detected but when trying to connect to it I get the upper error message. This is just for testing and I don't have an SSL cert yet but first I wanted to get this to work or do I require one? I tried lots of URL combinations found all over the web but none was working so far.

Just while writing I noticed that the socket is started from `/var/www/html_backend` and not `/var/www/html_backend/web` may the `DocumentRoot` cause issues with proxying?

I hope someone can point me in the right direction because all "working" solutions I found were not so helpful thus far.

Best Regards

Comment: check you ports are open.  Socket servers are a pain in the ....  I am not sure what you plan to use it for, but you may want to look into something like [RabbitMq](https://www.rabbitmq.com/), which is a message queue.  Fully mature, easy to use, salable etc.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix not the first time I hear that about sockets... xD, but yes ports are open.

Comment: I built one as a experiment about 3 years ago, then decided to use RabbitMq as it had more features then I could ever hope to build or maintain.

Comment: I'll give it a look, but for now I'd love to get this to work just for the sake of it

Comment: you didn't try `::1` but I doubt that is the issue.  What browser are you using, Chrome?  I just read chrome doesn't allow non SSL connections, you could try FIrefox.  I'll never suggest trying IE or Edge, I lived though the IE6 days... lol

Comment: I'll give Firefox a try later, messed a bit with the ports and can't open putty or ftp connection just now as I dont have my ssl keys with me.

Answer (score 1):

I build Websocket with PHP Linux and ratchet at Digitalocean and its working relay good, (my example its with wss but you can do it also with ws).

the way i build it:

Server side ratchet websocket:

```
$wsServer = new WsServer(new Chat);
    $server = IoServer::factory(
        new HttpServer($wsServer),
        8000
    );
```

Apache httpd-ssl.conf:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
ProxyPass /wss2/ ws://your.domain:8000
```

Your js file:

```
wss://your.domain/wss2/
```

than just run php websocket in ratchet with command: `php server.php`
and you good to go..

Comment: Is wss2 a default route when using `new WsServer(..);`? and have you tried it on a non default port / would `wss://your.domain:8080/wss2/` work as well in JS?

Comment: its not a default, this why we config the httpd-ssl file (default: your.domain). and you have to use same port in the server and in the client

Comment: Ok, but I mean in my code right now I have this `$app->route('/chat', new Chat());` and in my vhost `ProxyPass "/chat/" "ws://localhost:8888/"`. Do I have to connect to `ws://your.domain:8080/chat/chat` to fullfill that route or how does that work? But I will just try your sever creation code later. =)

Comment: add port to the route, and in your js change it to: ws://your.domain/chat (or just try my full comment)